# How to read data from Excel that has various types?

Tags: python, data-visualization, data-analysis

[image: dataset]

As the screenshot, the smartphone has two types which is S1,S2. And I want to make a data analysis based on different types. Firstly retrieve accoding to the smartphone type, but the first line's index is just the participant, but I can move the attribute of "Smartphone" into the first line too. so it is

```
data_s1=dataset[dataset['Smartphone']=='S1']
```

But how could I retrieve by gender? It is even not in the index line, and I couldn't remove the participant line. I am really strugguling.

Comment: You will need to find and install some third-party module that support doing it — there are a number of them available if you search for them.

Comment: could you please give an example?

Comment: Sorry, seeking recommendations for books, tools, software libraries, and more is not allowed on this site. Just do a simple search for the words python, excel, read, and files — there's a place at the very top of this page to type them in.